# Apply a shadow to a fitted image with Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I wrote this code:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="m-6 space-x-3">
  <div v-for="m in media" class="w-[200px] h-[200px] inline-block">
    <img class="object-contain w-full h-full shadow shadow-black" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300">
  </div>
  <div v-for="m in media" class="w-[200px] h-[200px] inline-block">
    <img class="object-contain w-full h-full shadow shadow-black" src="http://placekitten.com/300/200">
  </div>
</div>
```

It gives this result:

[image: screenshot]

But I want the shadow to apply to the image, not to the box that the image fits in.

Answer (score 2):

**Try to add drop-shadow instead of shadow**

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="m-6 space-x-3">
  <div v-for="m in media" class="w-[200px] h-[200px] inline-block">
    <img class="object-contain w-full h-full  drop-shadow-[0_5px_5px_rgba(0,0,0,0.5)]" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300">
  </div>
  <div v-for="m in media" class="w-[200px] h-[200px] inline-block">
    <img class="object-contain w-full h-full  drop-shadow-[0_5px_5px_rgba(0,0,0,0.5)]" src="http://placekitten.com/300/200">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Better. `drop-shadow` support seems a bit poor though, like it doesn't have the color shades for example.

Comment: hi! @AndreKR you can use RGb color for color shadows like this  drop-shadow-[0_5px_5px_rgba(255,0,0,0.5)].   this example is for red color (255,0,0,0.5)

Answer (score 1):

You can instead just extend the theme and use tailwind internal custom properties to get the color you want for the shadow.

[here is an example in play.tailwind](https://play.tailwindcss.com/1Q3jjfcIGy?file=config).

EDIT: Tailwind sample code into a snipet

```css
/* ! tailwindcss v3.2.6 | MIT License | https://tailwindcss.com */

/*
1. Prevent padding and border from affecting element width. (https://github.com/mozdevs/cssremedy/issues/4)
2. Allow adding a border to an element by just adding a border-width. (https://github.com/tailwindcss/tailwindcss/pull/116)
*/

*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* 1 */
  border-width: 0;
  /* 2 */
  border-style: solid;
  /* 2 */
  border-color: #e5e7eb;
  /* 2 */
}

::before,
::after {
  --tw-content: '';
}

/*
1. Use a consistent sensible line-height in all browsers.
2. Prevent adjustments of font size after orientation changes in iOS.
3. Use a more readable tab size.
4. Use the user's configured `sans` font-family by default.
5. Use the user's configured `sans` font-feature-settings by default.
*/

html {
  line-height: 1.5;
  /* 1 */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  /* 2 */
  -moz-tab-size: 4;
  /* 3 */
  tab-size: 4;
  /* 3 */
  font-family: ui-sans-serif, system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
  /* 4 */
  font-feature-settings: normal;
  /* 5 */
}

/*
1. Remove the margin in all browsers.
2. Inherit line-height from `html` so users can set them as a class directly on the `html` element.
*/

body {
  margin: 0;
  /* 1 */
  line-height: inherit;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
1. Add the correct height in Firefox.
2. Correct the inheritance of border color in Firefox. (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=190655)
3. Ensure horizontal rules are visible by default.
*/

hr {
  height: 0;
  /* 1 */
  color: inherit;
  /* 2 */
  border-top-width: 1px;
  /* 3 */
}

/*
Add the correct text decoration in Chrome, Edge, and Safari.
*/

abbr:where([title]) {
  -webkit-text-decoration: underline dotted;
          text-decoration: underline dotted;
}

/*
Remove the default font size and weight for headings.
*/

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
}

/*
Reset links to optimize for opt-in styling instead of opt-out.
*/

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}

/*
Add the correct font weight in Edge and Safari.
*/

b,
strong {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

/*
1. Use the user's configured `mono` font family by default.
2. Correct the odd `em` font sizing in all browsers.
*/

code,
kbd,
samp,
pre {
  font-family: ui-monospace, SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace;
  /* 1 */
  font-size: 1em;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
Add the correct font size in all browsers.
*/

small {
  font-size: 80%;
}

/*
Prevent `sub` and `sup` elements from affecting the line height in all browsers.
*/

sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

sub {
  bottom: -0.25em;
}

sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}

/*
1. Remove text indentation from table contents in Chrome and Safari. (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=999088, https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201297)
2. Correct table border color inheritance in all Chrome and Safari. (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=935729, https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=195016)
3. Remove gaps between table borders by default.
*/

table {
  text-indent: 0;
  /* 1 */
  border-color: inherit;
  /* 2 */
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /* 3 */
}

/*
1. Change the font styles in all browsers.
2. Remove the margin in Firefox and Safari.
3. Remove default padding in all browsers.
*/

button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
  /* 1 */
  font-size: 100%;
  /* 1 */
  font-weight: inherit;
  /* 1 */
  line-height: inherit;
  /* 1 */
  color: inherit;
  /* 1 */
  margin: 0;
  /* 2 */
  padding: 0;
  /* 3 */
}

/*
Remove the inheritance of text transform in Edge and Firefox.
*/

button,
select {
  text-transform: none;
}

/*
1. Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
2. Remove default button styles.
*/

button,
[type='button'],
[type='reset'],
[type='submit'] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  /* 1 */
  background-color: transparent;
  /* 2 */
  background-image: none;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
Use the modern Firefox focus style for all focusable elements.
*/

:-moz-focusring {
  outline: auto;
}

/*
Remove the additional `:invalid` styles in Firefox. (https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/2f9eacd9d3d995c937b4251a5557d95d494c9be1/layout/style/res/forms.css#L728-L737)
*/

:-moz-ui-invalid {
  box-shadow: none;
}

/*
Add the correct vertical alignment in Chrome and Firefox.
*/

progress {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/*
Correct the cursor style of increment and decrement buttons in Safari.
*/

::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  height: auto;
}

/*
1. Correct the odd appearance in Chrome and Safari.
2. Correct the outline style in Safari.
*/

[type='search'] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  /* 1 */
  outline-offset: -2px;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
Remove the inner padding in Chrome and Safari on macOS.
*/

::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/*
1. Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
2. Change font properties to `inherit` in Safari.
*/

::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  /* 1 */
  font: inherit;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
Add the correct display in Chrome and Safari.
*/

summary {
  display: list-item;
}

/*
Removes the default spacing and border for appropriate elements.
*/

blockquote,
dl,
dd,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
hr,
figure,
p,
pre {
  margin: 0;
}

fieldset {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

legend {
  padding: 0;
}

ol,
ul,
menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/*
Prevent resizing textareas horizontally by default.
*/

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

/*
1. Reset the default placeholder opacity in Firefox. (https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/3300)
2. Set the default placeholder color to the user's configured gray 400 color.
*/

input::placeholder,
textarea::placeholder {
  opacity: 1;
  /* 1 */
  color: #9ca3af;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
Set the default cursor for buttons.
*/

button,
[role="button"] {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*
Make sure disabled buttons don't get the pointer cursor.
*/

:disabled {
  cursor: default;
}

/*
1. Make replaced elements `display: block` by default. (https://github.com/mozdevs/cssremedy/issues/14)
2. Add `vertical-align: middle` to align replaced elements more sensibly by default. (https://github.com/jensimmons/cssremedy/issues/14#issuecomment-634934210)
   This can trigger a poorly considered lint error in some tools but is included by design.
*/

img,
svg,
video,
canvas,
audio,
iframe,
embed,
object {
  display: block;
  /* 1 */
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
Constrain images and videos to the parent width and preserve their intrinsic aspect ratio. (https://github.com/mozdevs/cssremedy/issues/14)
*/

img,
video {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

/* Make elements with the HTML hidden attribute stay hidden by default */

[hidden] {
  display: none;
}

*, ::before, ::after {
  --tw-border-spacing-x: 0;
  --tw-border-spacing-y: 0;
  --tw-translate-x: 0;
  --tw-translate-y: 0;
  --tw-rotate: 0;
  --tw-skew-x: 0;
  --tw-skew-y: 0;
  --tw-scale-x: 1;
  --tw-scale-y: 1;
  --tw-pan-x:  ;
  --tw-pan-y:  ;
  --tw-pinch-zoom:  ;
  --tw-scroll-snap-strictness: proximity;
  --tw-ordinal:  ;
  --tw-slashed-zero:  ;
  --tw-numeric-figure:  ;
  --tw-numeric-spacing:  ;
  --tw-numeric-fraction:  ;
  --tw-ring-inset:  ;
  --tw-ring-offset-width: 0px;
  --tw-ring-offset-color: #fff;
  --tw-ring-color: rgb(59 130 246 / 0.5);
  --tw-ring-offset-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-ring-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-shadow-colored: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-blur:  ;
  --tw-brightness:  ;
  --tw-contrast:  ;
  --tw-grayscale:  ;
  --tw-hue-rotate:  ;
  --tw-invert:  ;
  --tw-saturate:  ;
  --tw-sepia:  ;
  --tw-drop-shadow:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-blur:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-brightness:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-contrast:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-grayscale:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-hue-rotate:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-invert:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-opacity:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-saturate:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-sepia:  ;
}

::backdrop {
  --tw-border-spacing-x: 0;
  --tw-border-spacing-y: 0;
  --tw-translate-x: 0;
  --tw-translate-y: 0;
  --tw-rotate: 0;
  --tw-skew-x: 0;
  --tw-skew-y: 0;
  --tw-scale-x: 1;
  --tw-scale-y: 1;
  --tw-pan-x:  ;
  --tw-pan-y:  ;
  --tw-pinch-zoom:  ;
  --tw-scroll-snap-strictness: proximity;
  --tw-ordinal:  ;
  --tw-slashed-zero:  ;
  --tw-numeric-figure:  ;
  --tw-numeric-spacing:  ;
  --tw-numeric-fraction:  ;
  --tw-ring-inset:  ;
  --tw-ring-offset-width: 0px;
  --tw-ring-offset-color: #fff;
  --tw-ring-color: rgb(59 130 246 / 0.5);
  --tw-ring-offset-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-ring-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-shadow-colored: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-blur:  ;
  --tw-brightness:  ;
  --tw-contrast:  ;
  --tw-grayscale:  ;
  --tw-hue-rotate:  ;
  --tw-invert:  ;
  --tw-saturate:  ;
  --tw-sepia:  ;
  --tw-drop-shadow:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-blur:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-brightness:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-contrast:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-grayscale:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-hue-rotate:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-invert:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-opacity:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-saturate:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-sepia:  ;
}

.m-6 {
  margin: 1.5rem;
}

.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}

.h-\[200px\] {
  height: 200px;
}

.h-full {
  height: 100%;
}

.w-\[200px\] {
  width: 200px;
}

.w-full {
  width: 100%;
}

.space-x-3 > :not([hidden]) ~ :not([hidden]) {
  --tw-space-x-reverse: 0;
  margin-right: calc(0.75rem * var(--tw-space-x-reverse));
  margin-left: calc(0.75rem * calc(1 - var(--tw-space-x-reverse)));
}

.object-contain {
  object-fit: contain;
}

.shadow-blue-400 {
  --tw-shadow-color: #60a5fa;
  --tw-shadow: var(--tw-shadow-colored);
}

.shadow-gray-600 {
  --tw-shadow-color: #4b5563;
  --tw-shadow: var(--tw-shadow-colored);
}

.drop-shadow-custom {
  --tw-drop-shadow: drop-shadow(0 5px 5px var(--tw-shadow-color));
  filter: var(--tw-blur) var(--tw-brightness) var(--tw-contrast) var(--tw-grayscale) var(--tw-hue-rotate) var(--tw-invert) var(--tw-saturate) var(--tw-sepia) var(--tw-drop-shadow);
}
```

```html
<div class="m-6 space-x-3">
  <div v-for="m in media" class="w-[200px] h-[200px] inline-block">
    <img class="object-contain w-full h-full shadow-blue-400 drop-shadow-custom" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300">
  </div>
  <div v-for="m in media" class="w-[200px] h-[200px] inline-block">
    <img class="object-contain w-full h-full shadow-gray-600 drop-shadow-custom" src="http://placekitten.com/300/200">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Today I learned that CSS "variables" (custom properties) have scope. By the way, we should probably copy the code from the link into the answer.